# Evaluating $\iiint_E(x^2+y^2+z^2)\ dx\ dy\ dz$ where $E$ is an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have a practice exercise involving triple integrals and I'm not really sure where to start.

> Evaluate the triple integral
>   $$\iiint_E(x^2+y^2+z^2)\ dx\ dy\ dz$$
>   where $E$ is defined by $(\frac xa)^2+(\frac yb)^2+(\frac zc)^2\le1$ with $a,b,c\in\Bbb R^+$.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**:First substitute $x=aX , y=bY , z=cZ$. Now use spherical coordinates

Comment: how does this help us ? and how do we find the limits?

Comment: the way to go (+1)

Comment: @Hannah This substitution will make Ellipsoid to sphere.

Comment: Donot forget to put Jacobian.

Comment: Ahhh okay thank you so much

Comment: i have been at this question for hours and i still have no idea what im doing

Comment: @Hannah Watch this https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGqzsq0erqU7h6_bpE-CgJp4iX5aRju28

Comment: I aced in multivariable calc from these videos. He has explained concept of multiple integration very well along with questions. You will not have any doubt left after seeing these. Believe me. Multiple integration starts from video 8 i think. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Adapt spherical coordinates
$$\left.\eqalign{x&=r\cos\theta\cos\phi\cr y&=r\cos\theta\sin\phi\cr z&=r\sin\theta\cr}\right\},\qquad 0\leq r\leq R,\quad 0\leq\phi\leq2\pi, \quad -{\pi\over2}\leq\theta\leq{\pi\over2} $$
to the case of your ellipsoid, and write
$$\left.\eqalign{x&=a\>t\cos\theta\cos\phi\cr y&=b\>t\cos\theta\sin\phi\cr z&=c\>t\sin\theta\cr}\right\},\qquad 0\leq t\leq 1,\quad 0\leq\phi\leq2\pi, \quad -{\pi\over2}\leq\theta\leq{\pi\over2}\ .\tag{1} $$
Your triple integral then becomes
$$\eqalign{\int_E(x^2+y^2+z^2)\>{\rm d}(x,y,z)&=\cr\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}&\bigl(x^2(\ldots)+y^2(\ldots)+z^2(\ldots)\bigr)\>J(t,\phi,\theta)\>d\theta\>d\phi\>dt\ ,\cr}$$
where the $\ldots$ indicate that you have to plug in the resulting expressions in the variables $t$, $\phi$, $\theta$ (e.g., $x^2=a^2t^2\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi$), and $J$ denotes the Jacobian of $(1)$, which you have to compute beforehand.

Comment: for my resulting expressions where you have ... is that my $x^2+y^2+z^2$ in terms of t , ro and theeta in the order ?

Comment: @Hannah: See my edit.